# ssl certificates cleardb on heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, cleardb

I'm trying to use ssl with cleardb and rails

I've followed all steps on this link
(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#using-ssl-with-cleardb-and-rails) but I have a question :

how do I upload the certificates to my heroku instance ?

there's a not saying :

In this example, the
certificates are located in your application’s root directory. To specify a different directory, simply
prepend the path to the certificate.

but how do I upload this to my application root directory ? Do I need
to check this in my github repo ? it doesn't feel safe at all ?

Thanks a lot for your help
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I heard back from clearDB and heroku, and they told me to check in my certificates in my github repo, and that it wasn't a security breach

> the certificates *by themselves* do not provide any means by which to authenticate to the database (e.g., X.509 validation is not being used in conjunction with the credentials that you are required to provide in order to gain access to the database - this is by default on our Community pricing plans).